# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut in onPause

Tags: android, sqlite, timeout, activity-lifecycle

I have an app that allows users to input a lot of data while on one particular Activity screen. If the user navigates away from this screen suddenly for any reason, I save their data to the app's SQLite database. This app has been out for nearly 2 years and has never encountered the ANR timeout, but within the last month I've received 2 reports in the market.

In one case the problem occurred when trying to close the database. In the other case, the problem occurred when trying to open the database. I can't reproduce the problem at all, but I see the exact sequence of steps that are executing, but my problem is I don't know what I could possibly change. Both also revolved around securing a mutex for the database I don't create the mutex myself, this is a system thing.

Basically, onPause gets called, the database gets opened, I write the data to the file, and I close the database. As far as I understand it, this is the proper way to do things if your data isn't able to just be stored in SharedPreferences (which my data can not be).

I don't understand why an open or close of a database would take so long, so what are my options here? My only assumption is that these problems are arising from users who have had the app for a very long time, and thus their database files have grown extremely large, and perhaps it makes the system take longer to lock down the database file (I'm just guessing here).

I thought of maybe starting an AsyncTask from onPause, but that seems wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: I share the same problem, I called open and close in onStart and onStop. Got ANR, even tried to move them to onCreate and onDestroy(), same thing. Let me know if you have a solution for this.